# Роли не в таблице пользователей. Laravel

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, laravel, проектирование

Добрый день. Помогите решить проблему. Учусь работать с **Laravel** и пробую сделать систему авторизации с распределением прав.

Есть таблицы:

- сотрудников
- ролей
- пользователей
- смежная таблица сотрудники_роли (т.к. у одного сотрудника может быть несколько ролей).

Пользователи, которые могут авторизоваться хранятся в таблице users. Но роли есть не у пользователей (как это обычно бывает), а у сотрудников (это важно). То есть нужно как-то при авторизации обратиться к `users`, из неё вытащить сотрудника, посмотреть какие роли у него есть. Как это сделать в **Laravel**? Прикладываю схему бд, которую я попытался нарисовать.
[image: Схема бд]

Answer (score 1):

В модели `User` (для таблицы `users`), должна быть описана след. связь

```
public function member() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Member', 'member_id', 'id');
} 

public function roles() {
   return $this->member()->with('role');
}
```

В модели `Member` (таблица `members`)

```
public function role() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\MemberRole', 'id', 'id_member');
}
```

ну и сам вызов

```
User::with("roles")->get()
```

а дальше можешь уже модифицировать запросы, для выборки только конкретных полей и т.п.